Reconcile the Cable for connecting a Nvidia RTX 3090 FE to my Dual 6 Pin PSU
Context
I have a 3090 FE card with missing cables. I have orderd a cable(https://www.moddiy.com/products/Custom-Sleeved-PCIE-Modular-Cable-for-NVIDIA-RTX-30-Series-Mini-12-Pin.html) from MODDIY for it, but it is yet to arrive. I am not sure if its the right cable.
My current set of cables I have initially gotten for the job: https://a.co/d/1nfYDmQ and https://a.co/d/9QlK9UD were impossible for me to be convinced about that they would work. I DID NOT USE THEM. I am thoroughly confused - and hence scared about frying my equipment - about the pin layout and wiring for these PCIe power cavle connectors.
My PSU and the Nvidia 3090 FE

My PSU has two 6-Pin PCIe layout as shown above. I measured the lead voltages myself with a multimeter, without the GPU plugged in.

I will use the above pin layout for FE as above from Igor's Lab 2020 report
Furthermore in-order to get the right cables I thought I just need to know what are ground and what are 12V. Here was what the multimeter set to measure resistance told me:

This is where things really started to not make sense at all.
Questions

TL;DR Does someone know if the MODDIY cable is the right cable? At this point after ordering it, I am hoping it is but dunno.  Specifically, is my theory correct: Am I right that pins 1-6 are ground on the 3090 FE and not 12V? And if so, hence should I connect the each of my PSU's dual 6-Pin PCIe 12V pins #1-3 to the 12 V pins #7-12 of the 3090?

If I am correct in assessing that pins 1-6 of the 3090 FE are Ground,  Is it a divergence that these are different from the PCIe layout standard?

If pin 1-6 are indeed ground then lets look at the 12 V pins. Why are Pins 7, 8 and separately Pin 11, 12 appear fused (i.e. 0 resistance with the multimeter?). Although I am not sure how this affects the power cable I get.


UPDATE: I did try to find the connector based on this GN teardown to see if I could find insights. It seems like an Astrom part, but there are literally no details and a pin spec by NVIDIA or any one.

These connectors are standardized so that you can't make a mistake about connecting 12V to ground anywhere. If the cables and adapters you had already didn't work it might be more of an issue with current limits in your PSU. You shouldn't be splitting 2 PCIe ATX connectors into 4 like that because it allows the 4 connectors to draw too much current over the original two connectors. Your PSU might be saving you from starting a fire and preventing the GPU from staying on after a current spike.

@Romen Thanks. Actually I did not even try the old cables since I could not be confident. Right now the MODDIY cable which I have yet to get, is just a single split Y cable.
Regarding: These connectors are standardized so that you can't make a mistake about connecting 12V to ground anywhere
I am sure I won't connect GND to 12V on the PSU itself or the 3090 itself. I am more worried about 12V from PSU going to the right 12 V Pin on the 3090.

https://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/GEFORCE_RTX_3090_USER_GUIDE_v01.pdf You need 2x 8-pin connectors from the PSU. Not 6-pin.

@York I plan to use a 8 pin to 6+2 pin adapter in case that is what MODDIY sends me. My Lenovo PSU is a bit different from others and exposes the 6 pin lines see page 5 here.

That is indeed "a bit different" from most PSUs. The connector on the board seems to be a normal ATX 6 pin PCIe connector? Note that these are rated for only 75W of power so if you use splitters you risk running too much current through the connector. The 16 pin 12VHPWR connector on your RTX 3090 can draw over 300W, which is not possible to safely pull through two 6-pin PCIe ATX connectors. The Dell manual recommends unsafe splitters and so this system cannot safely run an RTX 3090. You should use a different PSU to do this safely.

I think you're over-thinking this by looking at the pinouts. These 12VHPWR and PCIe connectors have multiple pins only because they are multiple wires. On the GPU and PSU side they're bonded to allow a higher total amperage over multiple wires. A single wire coming out of the connector has a max current it's rated for. All of the 12V pins on  the PSU side usually come from the same 12V rail. The ATX standard exists to ensure things are connected safely without needing to know these details.

@Romen
So what you are saying is true but I think this is technically correct, yet the 8 Pin is just a 6+2 pin where the last 2 are grounds and it can support more:
1/n. The first clue is in the lenovo extended docs supporting GPUs like the RTX Quadro 4000 which needs 160W and P520 can support two of them

@Romen 2/n. The second practical clue was from this guy actually connecting his Gigabyte RTX 3090 to the P520 which needs 350W:

@Romen 3/n. The overall understanding of the 6 pin, 8 pin and 6+2 pin PCIe standard came from here which also mentions that most PSUs can support 4-4.5 Amps on every 12V rail which is closer to ~144W total for 6-pin, yet the PCIe Standard mentions that 75W is total  which is misleading.

I only mean to say it's not safe to split PCIe 6-Pin into multiple connectors like this. Yes it's practically possible, and then it's also possible for these wires to catch fire like that. A single PCIe 6-pin connector can carry more than 75W physically, but power supplies are usually designed to limit the current from their end because that is what the ATX standard specifies is the max for the connector. If the adapters you already have didn't work it's very likely because of this safety feature in your PSU, not a pinout problem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The heart of the question is safely connecting and operating your GPU, and I don't think that your questions about the board's power design or connector pinout are the right place to focus.
The MODDIY cable linked is a custom cable. It will definitely connect your GPU to power, but whether or not it is "right" depends on if you provided the correct specification to MODDIY when you placed the order, and if they assembled it correctly. I have used MODDIY cables in the past and would be surprised if it were incorrectly made. Since there is no universal standard pinout for the PSU side of a modular PSU connectors (only on the device end is standardized) specifying the wrong PSU could result in a custom cable that doesn't fit, or fits but doesn't work or damages your system.
The custom cable would replace the PSU’s PCIe Power cables and directly connect your PSU to the GPU. It's important to keep in mind that the GeForce RTX 3090 Founder's Edition has a TGP of 350W, which can be safely drawn from 2x 8-pin PCIe Power cables (through your missing adapter) plus the motherboard. If your PSU is capable of supporting this load from its two PSU-side connectors, and you provided the appropriate model number for MODDIY, then their cable should be good to go.

Somewhat worryingly, you mention 2x 6-pin PCIe Power cables - if this is the max supported by your PSU then you may need to replace the PSU with one designed for higher power. The recommended PSU for an RTX 3090 is 750W or more. 6-pin PCIe power cables are rated 75W, while the 8-pin versions are rated for 150W. Most 6-pin cables implement an optional 3rd +12V connector which provides the same number of +12V terminals as the 8-pin version. It's generally, but not always, possible to use a 6-pin to 8-pin adapter with these cables, since the extra 2 pins are just additional grounds. Commonly these grounds are fused/sourced from another of the 3 grounds on the typical 6+2 style PCIe power cables.
The RTX 3090's PCIe pinout is below, but it's really the PSU side that you should be concerned with when ordering custom cables. All RTX 3090 FEs use the same pinout, so any cable or adapter designed for it should work, and the exact pinout probably isn't germane. Note that 3090 TI and RTX 40-series (12VHPWR - your first Amazon link) cables/connectors are not compatible with an RTX 3090 FE. 

Thanks @Amorphous. My lenovo P520 900 W PSU does mention it support for 2 RTX Quadro 4000 which needs 160W each + 75 W is available from the PCIe x16 slot.
Also there is this guy actually connecting his Gigabyte OC RTX 3090 to this machine.
So I am fairly confident of this setup working.

You mentioned: It's generally, but not always, possible to use a 6-pin to 8-pin adapter with these cables, since the extra 2 pins are just additional grounds.
So I have 12V on all 3 of the 6-Pin's PSU rails. Logically speaking, Is determining what 8 pin to 6+2 pin cable works, done by checking if all 6 rails(from 2*6Pin PSU connectors) connect to all the 12 pins using a multimeter?

If you mean going from a 6-pin to an 8-pin, it depends on the PSU, AWG of the conductors, and the terminal housings. Sounds like an OEM system, if it's available with 2x 6-to-8-pin adapters, then it should be safe to use in that configuration. If not, you shouldn't consider moving forward with your current PSU. There's no safety built into the wire or the terminal, you absolutely can melt a terminal housing or the wire's insulator. Your PSU may have enough protection to shut down your system, or it could cause a short or fire. Two Quadro RTX 4000s are 100W less TGP than an RTX 3090.
